# “you are referring to” vs “are you referring to”?

Tags: questions

Which one of the followings is correct?

> Which one **you are** referring to?
>
> Which one **are you** referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking a question, the correct answer would be

> Which one **are you** referring to?

Unless you phrased the question:

> You are referring to which one?